# I'm python beginner and while writing the code, It seems too repetitive and I broke the DRY rule. What should do to fix or clean up this code?

Tags: python, if-statement, window, project, dry

```
choice = input("Choose Right(r) or LEfT(l): ")
if choice == "r":
    print("")
    choiceR2 = input("Choose Right(r) or LEfT(l): ")
    if choiceR2 == "r":
        print("")
        choiceR3 =input("Choose Right(r) or LEfT(l): ")
        if choiceR3 == "r":
            print("")
        elif choiceR3 == "l":
            print("")
    elif choiceR2 == "l":
        print("")
        choiceR4=input("Choose Right(r) or LEfT(l): ")
        if choiceR4 == "r":
            print("")
        elif choiceR4 == "l":
            print("")
elif choice == "l":
    print("")
    choiceL2 = input("Choose Right(r) or LEfT(l): ")
    if choiceL2 == "r":
        print("")
        choiceL3 =input("Choose Right(r) or LEfT(l): ")
        if choiceL3 == "r":
            print("")
        elif choiceL3 == "l":
            print("")
    elif choiceL2 == "l":
        print("")
        choiceL4=input("Choose Right(r) or LEfT(l): ")
        if choiceL4 == "r":
            print("")
        elif choiceL4 == "l":
            print("")
```

I want the user to choose to go left or right and whatever they choose, there will be another left or choice. This will go on until three time. I was writing place holders and it look very repetitive to me. After each question, there will be a different dialogue, like ( you choose left and see a dark hall. will you advance left or right from here?

Comment: If the code is working you should post in [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Guy, the question needs work before it's suited to [codereview.se]. You should have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the *purpose* of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code *does* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.

Comment: I will keep it in mind. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

```
choice = input("Choose Right(r) or LEfT(l): ")
print("")
choiceR2 = input("Choose Right(r) or LEfT(l): ")
print("")
choiceR3 = input("Choose Right(r) or LEfT(l): ")
print("")
choiceR4 = input("Choose Right(r) or LEfT(l): ")
print("")
print("Your choices were", choice, choiceR2, choiceR3, choiceR4)
```

this should work, you don't need to do all those if/else statements...

Comment: I think you don't get it. please go through one more time his question. Your code is not dependent on user value. it simply print same for the both `r` and `l` case

Answer (score 0):

As you ask user to choice 4 times.. **Note you can change as per your reference**

**Code:-**

```
i=1
while i<5:    
    ask=input("Choose Right(r) or LEfT(l): ")
    if ask=="r":
        print("choice "+str(i)+": You choose to go Right")
    else:
        print("choice "+str(i)+": You choose to go Left")
    i+=1
```

**Output:-**

```
Choose Right(r) or LEfT(l): l
choice 1: You choose to go Left
Choose Right(r) or LEfT(l): r
choice 2: You choose to go Right
Choose Right(r) or LEfT(l): r
choice 3: You choose to go Right
Choose Right(r) or LEfT(l): l
choice 4: You choose to go Left
```

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to add something to the question. After each question, there will be a different dialogue, like ( you choose left and see a dark hall. will you advance left or right from here?)

Comment: ok. try to detailing your question [update], for each cases. than I can help in better way